# Unable to retrieve javax.websocket.server.ServerContainer from ServletContext in Spring Boot (Tomcat application)

Tags: spring-boot, websocket, tomcat8

I have a spring boot application using spring-boot-starter-tomcat. I am trying to add a custom websocket endpoint in the application class.

To do this, I am trying to retrieve the `ServerContainer` with following:

```
 ServerContainer container = (ServerContainer)servletContext.getAttribute(ServerContainer.class.getName());
```

However, the container is null, even though the tomcat server seems to come up in the spring boot application.

Is there any way to initialize the javax.websocket.server.ServerContainer in a spring boot application?